# Where can I set the default user group?

Tags: user-groups

Whenever I create a new user group it sets it to a user group we created called "Basic".

This is very annoying as it means it doesn't show up a lot of the time.

Is there somewhere we can set this back to public?

Comment: When you say '...it sets it to a user group', what is it? Do you mean the Parent Group is set to Basic when the group is created. And are you talking about J4 or J3?

Comment: J3.  I mean when I create a new module the user group is "basic" and not "public" so we have to remember to change it each time.

Comment: There is no user group field in modules. Maybe you mean access level?

Comment: Yes access level will be what I mean